# How to make a css navigation menu "selected" option still clickable

Tags: css, inheritance, hover

So I have a fairly simple vertical CSS menu based off of UL.

```
<ul class="vertnav">
<li><a href="unselected1.php">Item1</a></li>
<li><a href="unselected2.php">Item2</a></li>
<li><a href="selected.php" class="vertnavdown">Selected</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want three basic colors (say tan for default LI, orange for VERTNAVDOWN, and red for A:HOVER. However I can't seem to get the vertnavdown class to inherit right, and the `.vertnav li a:visited` overrides it every time. if I use `!important` to force it through I can't seem to also get the hover to work.

Any suggestions? I thought I understood inheritance in CSS but I guess I don't.

```
.vertnav{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
width: 172px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align: left;
height: 45px;
}
.vertnav li{
margin: 0px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
border-bottom: 0px none;
border-right: 0px none;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
border-left: 0px none;
text-align: left;
height: 45px;
width: 172px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.vertnav li a{
display: block;
text-align: left;   
color: #666666;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #FFEEC1;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 15px;
height: 45px;
}
.vertnav li a:visited{
display: block;
text-align: left;   
color: #666666;
background-color: #FFEEC1;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 15px;
height: 45px;
}
.vertnav li a:hover{
color: white;
background-color: #ffbf0c;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
height: 45px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
}
.vertnavdown a
{
display:block;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #ff9000;
}
.vertnavdown a:hover
{
background-color: #ffbf0c;
}
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Edited to add CSS. ^^^^^^

Comment: It sounds like the problem is specificity of the rules, and not a matter of inheritance. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Comment: There also is a nice post on shmashing magazine concerning this topic.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you could post the css as well.

What you normally need is something like this

`<ul id="nav">

    <li><a>one</a></li>

    <li class="active"><a>two</a></li>

</ul>`

the css would be:

`#nav li{

    color: red;

}

 #nav li a:visited{

  color: green;

}

 #nav li.active a{

    color: blue;

}`

you need to be more specific with the active css naming.

Answer (score 2):

`.vertnav li a:visited` is very specific, and in CSS, more specific overrides less specific, even if the less specific CSS comes later in the inheritance chain.

`.vertnavdown` on it's own will **always** be overridden by `.vertnav li a:visited` -- the best solution is to be more specific with your description of `.vertnavdown`.

Changing `.vertnavdown a` and `.vertnavdown a:hover` to
`.vertnav ul li a.vertnavdown` `.vertnav ul li a.vertnavdown:hover` will fix your problem.

### EDIT:

*Smacks head* Apologies, I should have noted that you were trying to fix a problem with the `:visited` links ... Since you haven't specified a style for `a.vertnavdown:visited` it inherits the style of `.vertnav a:visited`.

The solution then is to add  `a.vertnavdown:visited` to whatever style declaration you want it to inherit from.  **That** should fix the problem.

Comment: I feel like this should be the solution, but it's not actually working. Hrm.

Comment: @aslum; added a fix that will actually fix the problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with .vertnav li a:visited .vertnavdown